# Displaying List as Table Row + Inserting Content as Table Cell Before Each Row - How to Skip Adding content to First Li?

Tags: html, css, list

I have this working code which currently:

1. Removes the default list bullet symbol on a list and inserts a wingbat pointing hand symbol instead.
2. Adds a drop shadow border effect to the top edge of each li, but skips the first li.

I want to now use the first li as a header thus I want to skip adding the wingbat symbol on 1st li (i.e., I want the wingbats to start with the second li).

```
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 0em;
text-indext: -1em;
display: table;
}

.post-body ul li{
display: table-row;
}

.post-body ul li::before{
content:"\261e";
color: #8d8d8d;
text-align: right;
padding-right: .6em;
display: table-cell;
}

.post-body ul li + li{
-moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #8d8d8d;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #8d8d8d;
box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #8d8d8d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to specify the css for the first li element alone. E.g.

```
ul > li:first-child{
color:blue;
}
```